# Do the expressions for conditional probability with unions expand like this

Tags: probability

Is it correct that:

$$\Pr[A \mid B \cap C \cap D] = \frac{\Pr[A \cap B  \mid C \cap D]}{\Pr[ B \mid C \cap D] }$$

Comment: Why not just _write down_ the _definitions_ of the two conditional probabilities on the right and see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  All probabilities are conditional; one always has a smaple space $\Omega$ of probability $1$ and every probability is a probability of some set $A\subseteq\Omega$ are of the form
$$
\Pr(A) = \Pr(A\mid\Omega) = \frac{\Pr(A\cap\Omega)}{\Pr(\Omega)}.
$$
You're looking at the case in which $\Omega$ is narrowed down to the set $C\cap D$ and then further narrowed down from there, to $B\cap C\cap D$.